# Netbeans Error: The folder name is not valid (when creating a new file)

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to create a new file however I keep getting the error `The Folder Name is not valid` whereas the file path to that directory most definitely exists

here is a screen shot [image]

Has anyone ever encountered this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem 1: Drive C: and/or further folder structure does not exist on your computer

Possible problem 2: You don't have write permissions for that folder

Possible problem 3: It is hosted on *nix and therefore case sensitive...

In Netbeans 6.8 there was a bug like this. Take a look

[Bug 177353 - The Folder Name is not valid](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=177353)